# Working with vector of vector with unknown length

Tags: c++, vector, adjacency-list

I am trying to create adjacency list using vector of vector. The number of nodes is not known at the start of code, and is instead taken as input from console. The nodes are numbered 1 onwards. Below is the code

```
class Graph {
public:
    int numNodes;
    vector<vector<int>> g;

    Graph(int n):numNodes(n) {
        for(int i=0;i < n;i++)
        {
            vector<int> v;
            g.push_back(v);
        }
    }

    void add_edge(int u, int v) {
        cout << "adding edge from " << u << " " << v << endl;

        g[u-1].push_back(v-1);
        g[v-1].push_back(u-1);
        cout << "added " << endl;
    }
}
```

Apparently, when calling add_edge, it never prints `added`.

What's the reason?

Additioanlly

When I change my code

```
g[u-1].push_back(v-1);
```

To

```
vector<int> a = g[v-1];
g[u-1].push_back(v-1);
```

it works fine.

My main is code below,

```
    int n, m;
    cin >> n; //number of nodes
    Graph graph(n);
    cin >> m; //number of edges
    // read and set edges
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int u, v; //to and from vertex;
        cin >> u >> v;
        u--, v--;
        // add each edge to the graph
        graph.add_edge(u, v);
    }
```

Comment: What are the values of u, v and n you are using? Try to make a [mcve]

Comment: @P.W done. updated,

Comment: You seem to be doing the -1 twice. Once in add_edge and once when reading.

Comment: @AnubhavSrivastava thanks, but do you know why does it work when i explicitly take the vector instance and push back to that?

Comment: No idea but I'd chock it up to undefined behavior being just that: undefined. Sometimes your code will work when it isn't correct. For example, if I compile with different flags I can make your original program crash on both versions.

Comment: You never check whether `u-1` or `v-1` are valid indexes. If `u` is `0` index will be invalid.

Comment: Getting the correct result and having not error message or crash, does not mean that your code works. So if you add a `vector<int> a = g[v-1];` and your code "works" then you can be sure that you have a bug in your code that causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you replace `g[u-1]` and `g[v-1]` with  `g.at(u-1)` and `g.at(v-1)`, then boundary checks are done and you get a `terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector` telling you that you try to access an index that doe not exists.